# Disable Touch of inner RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to RecyclerView and I want to implement OnItemClickListner like Listview. To do this I'm using following code.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewIngredient);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //Item Click Listner  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is working fine. The problem is I have another Recyclerview inside this Recyclerview. If I tap on inner recycler view, Item Click listner for parent view did not respond. I don't wan't to make inner recyclerview clickable.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Maybe a stuped decision but did yout try  set "clickable='true'" to parent recyclerview?

Comment: Yes, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use interface with inner RecycleView Class get it's clickListener into parent RecycleView Class.This will work.

Here is Sample

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<String> strings ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    strings = new ArrayList<>();

    strings.add("A");
    strings.add("B");
    strings.add("C");
    strings.add("D");
    strings.add("E");
    strings.add("F");
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(strings));
    recyclerView.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

and Parent Adapter is

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<String> strings;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    this.strings=strings;
}

@Override
public  ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,200));
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final  ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.textView.setText(strings.get(position));
    holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyChildAdapter(strings, new setOnClick() {
        @Override
        public void setOnClick() {
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView .getContext(),"FF  F",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return strings.size();
}


 static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     TextView textView;
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
         recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view. findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"FFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and ChildAdapter Is

```
 public class MyChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyChildAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<String> strings;
static setOnClick setOnClick;
public MyChildAdapter(ArrayList<String> strings, setOnClick setOnClick) {
    this.strings=strings;
    this.setOnClick = setOnClick;
}

@Override
public  ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter, parent, false);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,100));
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.textView.setText(strings.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return strings.size();
}


 static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      /*  view.setClickable(false);
        view.setFocusable(false);
        view.setEnabled(false);*/
      view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              setOnClick.setOnClick();
              }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

and Interface is

```
interface   setOnClick{
void  setOnClick();
}
```

and adapter.xml layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"

       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please give me some code sample or any useful link.

Answer (score 6):

The most simple way is creating own `RecyclerView`, override `onTouchEvent` and use it in your XML layout or code.

```
public class MyDisabledRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can re-use that widget in other places without any extra logic.

Answer (score 1):

Take a static variable and set it to false if u have clicked some item in the Parent recyclerView. Now using this flag

if(parent)

{

//set the listner for the View

}

Now no listner is set for your child recyclerview to respond

Comment: Didn't set any listner for child recyclerview.

Comment: @user2566484 since you are using the same adapter for both parent and child ,listner for the child is automatically set when it goes through the code of   itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())

Comment: for child I have different adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to disable user interaction

```
mRecyclerView.suppressLayout(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
viewHolder.someInnerRecyclerView.suppressLayout(true);
viewHolder.someInnerRecyclerView.setFocusable(false);
viewHolder.someInnerRecyclerView.setClickable(false);
```