# Child RecyclerView item intercepts click event of parent RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[Parent item click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfS42.png)

[Child item click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc407.png)

I have a parent RecyclerView with nested child RecyclerView items inside. The problem is that I only click on the non-child RecyclerView part of the parent item to trigger the click event of the parent RecyclerView. Clicking on the child RecyclerView item will intercept the click event. I would like to know how to cancel the click interception of the child RecyclerView item and pass the click on it. Go to the parent RecyclerView item so that I can display the wave effect and trigger the unique click event regardless of the area in the parent RecyclerView item.

Here is my adapter code:

```
parentAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position ->
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putSerializable("record", recordAdapter.data[position])
    ActivityUtils.startActivity(bundle, RecordDetailActivity::class.java)
}
```

parent adapter

```
class RecordAdapter : BaseQuickAdapter<Record, BaseViewHolder>(R.layout.item_record) {
    override fun convert(helper: BaseViewHolder, item: Record) {
        ...

        val adapter = ChildAdapter()
        val recyclerView = helper.getView<RecyclerView>(R.id.item_record_product_rv)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(mContext, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        adapter.bindToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        adapter.setNewData(item.productInfo)
    }
}
```

child adapter

```
class RecordProductAdapter : BaseQuickAdapter<RecordProduct<String, String, Double, Int>, BaseViewHolder>(R.layout.item_record_product) {
    override fun convert(helper: BaseViewHolder, item: RecordProduct<String, String, Double, Int>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37155806/6504294 this answer works, but I wonder if there is a simple way to do it (not using custom view)